# Unable to read bin file in React native CLI

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, model, readfile, bin

Unable to read file """"""""const modelWeights = require('../model/weights.bin');""""""""

[Here is my dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFYzb.png)

[Here is my metro config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQPrE.png)

[Here is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceCVx.png)

Comment: Could you move your code and all relevant details to this question directly ? The images can be removed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.